# // DRAW HERE .... Well, what do I 'draw' here?

Tags: java

I have this code

```
public void paint(Graphics g) { super.paint(g); // DRAW HERE }
```

But, what do I actually draw there?

I am making a game in Java, here is my source code
**GAME.JAVA**

```
package com.cmnatic.cmnatic;


import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.DataBufferInt;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import com.cmnatic.cmnatic.graphics.Screen;


public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable {



private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final Screen Screen = null;
    public static int width = 300;
    public static int height = width / 16 * 9;  // 168
    public static int scale = 3;

    private Thread thread;
    private JFrame frame;
    private boolean running = false;

    public void paint(Graphics g) { super.paint(g); } // 1280x720 }

    private Screen screen;

    private BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    private int[] pixels = ((DataBufferInt)image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();

    public Game() {
        Dimension size = new Dimension(width * scale, height * scale);
        setPreferredSize(size);

        screen =  new Screen(width, height);

        frame = new JFrame();
   }

    public synchronized void start() {
        running = true;
        thread = new Thread(this, "Display");
        thread.start();
    }

    public synchronized void stop() {
        running = false;
        try {
            thread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        while (running == true) {
            update();
            render();
        }
    }

    public void update() {

    }

    public void render() {
        BufferStrategy bs = getBufferStrategy();
        if (bs == null) {
            createBufferStrategy(3);
            return;
        }

        screen.clear();

        screen.render();

        for (int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++) {
            pixels[i] = screen.pixels[i];
        }

        Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);
        g.dispose();
        bs.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Game game = new Game();
        game.frame.setResizable(false);
        game.frame.setTitle("The Last Hit");
        game.frame.add(game);
        game.frame.pack();
        game.frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        game.frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        game.frame.setVisible(true);

        game.start();
    }

    public static Screen getScreen() {
        return Screen;
    }

}
```

Also, here is my Screen.java

```
package com.cmnatic.cmnatic.graphics;

public class Screen {


    private int width, height;
    public int[] pixels;

    int xtime = 0, ytime = 50;
    int counter = 0;

    public Screen(int width, int height) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        pixels = new int[width * height]; // 0 - 50,399 = 50,400
    }

    public void clear() {
        for (int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++) {
            pixels[i] = 0;
        }
    }

    public void render()  {
        counter++;
        if (counter % 100 == 0) {
            xtime--;
        if (counter % 100 == 0) {
            ytime--;

        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)  {
            if (ytime >= height) break;
             for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)  { 
                 if (xtime >= width) break;
                 pixels[xtime + ytime * width] = 0xff00ff;
             }


        }
   }
}
}
}
```

So, as the question asks, what do I put in in the `// DRAW HERE`

Thanks,
CMNatic

Comment: *"// DRAW HERE … Well, what do I 'draw' here?"*  Draw a pony.. No!  A clown!

Comment: But i'm seeing `1280x720` let me recheck it's `921600`.

Comment: Take a look at this please: http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you want to draw, for example a rectangle

```
    super.paintComponent(graphics);
    graphics.setColor(Color.RED);
    graphics.drawRect(0, 5, 100, 100);
```

Take a look at this for example: http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/javax.swing/JPanelpaintComponentGraphicsg.htm

Answer (score 1):

First look at your `render` method, do you see these three lines -

```
g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);
```

I'd try moving them to the paint like so -

```
public void paint(Graphics g) { 
  super.paint(g);
  g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
  g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
  // Java GUI components implement ImageObserver (_need_ this).
  g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
}
```

Comment: `g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);` should be `g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);`.  Java GUI components **implement** `ImageObserver`..